# How to download file in pdf with selenium edge web driver in specific custom folder in python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, microsoft-edge

I am using selenium webdriver to automate downloading several PDF files. I get the PDF preview window (see below), and now I would like to download the file. How can I accomplish this using edge as the browser?

[Sample Screenshot i want to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY5EP.png)

Here's I've got so far but it's not working.

```
path = "F:\Anuzz\Desktop\sel\msedgedriver.exe"
options = EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": "F:\Anuzz\Desktop\sel\test.py",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,   
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
})
driver = Edge(path, options=options)
driver.get('https://sscstudy.com/ssc-chsl-paper-pdf-download/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-11490"]/div/div/p[4]/a/strong').click()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW (works on edge)

To use this you have to install `pyautogui` library with the command `pip install pyautogui`

```
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()

pdf_url = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'
driver.get(pdf_url)

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(2)
path_and_filename = r'C:\Users\gt\Desktop\test.pdf'
pyautogui.typewrite(path_and_filename)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

---

OLD (works on chrome)

This is the code I use to automatically download a pdf to a specific path. If you have windows, just put your account name in `r'C:\Users\...\Desktop'`. Moreover, you have to put the path of your driver in `chromedriver_path`. The code below downloads a sample pdf.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
download_path = r'C:\Users\...\Desktop'
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": download_path, # change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, # to auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True # it will not show PDF directly in chrome
})

chromedriver_path = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(chromedriver_path))

pdf_url = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'
driver.get(pdf_url)
```

Comment: Yeah ! its working fine for chrome but I want to do the same thing with edge

Comment: @Anuj to my knowledge it is not possible on Edge, see updated answer

Comment: Any workaround for edge ?

Comment: @Anuj I updated the answer with a working method for Edge :)

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I think that the problem is mainly caused by the site you provided, which seems to embed other PDF viewers instead of the one that comes with Edge.

So you may need code like this to achieve your needs( url splicing ):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service
import time

edgeOption = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edgeOption.use_chromium = True
edgeOption.add_argument("start-maximized")
edgeOption.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": "C:\\Downloads",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False
})
edgeOption.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
s=service.Service(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s, options=edgeOption)

driver.get('https://sscstudy.com/ssc-chsl-paper-pdf-download/')
url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-11490"]/div/div/p[4]/a').get_attribute('href')

driver.get("https://drive.google.com/uc?id="+url[32:(len(url)-17)]+"&export=download")
time.sleep(1)
```

**Note**: Test with `Selenium 4.1.0` and `Edge 101.0.1210.53`. Please modify path of the Edge Driver and other possible parameters according to your own situation.